# Replacing values in multiple columnns R

Tags: r, database, replace

I am struggling with some replacement of values in R, and I would like to hear your suggestion on how to proceed. In resume, I have a data with an index, and I need to replace the values of this index for another one. Considering I have 5564 cases on both index, I want to know how to make it in the entire data.

Suppose this is my data.frame 1:

```
a<-sample(1:10, 10);b<- sample(1:10,10); c<- sample(1:10,10) 
d<-sample(1:10, 10)
df1<- cbind(a, b, c, d)
       a  b  c  d
 [1,]  3  4  7  5
 [2,]  2  2  1  7
 [3,]  9  8 10  8
 [4,]  1  1  3  2
 [5,]  7  5  2  9
 [6,] 10  7  4  3
 [7,]  8  3  8  6
 [8,]  6  6  5  1
 [9,]  5 10  9 10
 [10,]  4  9  6  4
```

Now, my second data with the second index

```
 index1<- c(1:10) ; index2 <- sample(1:1000, 10)
 df2<- cbind(index1, index2)
            index1 index2
    [1,]      1    877
    [2,]      2    241
    [3,]      3    924
    [4,]      4    197
    [5,]      5    405
    [6,]      6    854
    [7,]      7    852
    [8,]      8    772
    [9,]      9    421
    [10,]     10    646
```

In resume, I need to replace the values of index 1, of df1, by the equivalent values of the index2 in df2. I truly have no ideia how to solve this, so any help will be very welcome.

Thanks!

Comment: df1 doesn't have an index1. Can you show the output you want?

Comment: Hi Eric! Thanks for answering. The index on df1 are the values. These values are the same of the index 1 of DF 2, and I need to replace them for the values on index 2 of df2

Comment: Could you make your code reproducible? `samples` should be `sample` and you will need to use `set.seed(1)` for example to make sure you get the same results every time when taking a 'random' sample. Are you sure you want to `cbind(...)` as well - are each of your real `df1` and `df2` a `matrix`, or a `data.frame`? This will affect what the answer might be.

Comment: Sorry for the typo in the sample function, but I have already solved with the suggestions below!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not sure that you want this :

```
for ( i in seq_len(nrow(df2))){

    df1[df1 == df2[,"index1"][i]] <- df2[,"index2"][i]

}
df1
```

If the solution is ok, we maybe can find a faster way.

Answer (score 1):

I would make use of the match function. Long story short:

`df1[which(df1 %in% df2[,"index1"])] <- df2[,"index2"][match(df1, df2[,"index1"])]`

I'll explain:

```
df1 <- cbind(a = sample(1:10, 10), b = sample(1:10, 10), 
            c = sample(1:10, 10), d = sample(1:10, 10))
df2 <- cbind(index1 = 1:10, index2 = sample(1:1000, 10))

df.original <- df1 # to see

df1
#       a  b  c  d
# [1,]  1  1  8  6
# [2,]  2  6  1  9
# [3,]  3  2  2  4
# [4,]  7  9  9  8
# [5,]  8  7 10  5
# [6,] 10 10  3  2
# [7,]  6  5  6 10
# [8,]  9  4  4  3
# [9,]  5  3  7  7
#[10,]  4  8  5  1
```

To find which will be switched (position in vector)

```
pos <- which(df1 %in% df2[,"index1"]) 
df1[pos] == df1 # it's the same thing
#         a    b    c    d
# [1,] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
# [2,] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
# [3,] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
# [4,] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
# [5,] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
# [6,] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
# [7,] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
# [8,] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
# [9,] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
#[10,] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
```

Here every value will be swapped but that may not necessarily be the case. That's why it is important to find a position value using `%in%` as above.

To find which of them are in df2 index1

```
tomatch <- match(df1, df2[,"index1"]) # all of them.
tomatch
# [1]  1  2  3  7  8 10  6  9  5  4  1  6  2  9  7 10  5  4  3  8  8  1  2  9 10
#[26]  3  6  4  7  5  6  9  4  8  5  2 10  3  7  1
df2[,"index2"][tomatch] # what we want to replace them with
# [1] 829 568 836 717 693  92 645 222 767 107 829 645 568 222 717  92 767 107
#[19] 836 693 693 829 568 222  92 836 645 107 717 767 645 222 107 693 767 568
#[37]  92 836 717 829
df1[pos] <- df2[,"index2"][tomatch]
df1
#        a   b   c   d
# [1,] 829 829 693 645
# [2,] 568 645 829 222
# [3,] 836 568 568 107
# [4,] 717 222 222 693
# [5,] 693 717  92 767
# [6,]  92  92 836 568
# [7,] 645 767 645  92
# [8,] 222 107 107 836
# [9,] 767 836 717 717
#[10,] 107 693 767 829
```

Also, using data.frames can be a little cleaner to read
`df1[which(df1 %in% df2$index1)] <- df2$index2[match(df1, df2$index1)]`

Comment: Thanks for the solution! I will check the details here. Since I still need to figure out some of the future steps I plan with this data, I am quite sure your entire explanation will help me imensily

Answer (score 0):

A solution using `dplyr` and `tidyr`. `df1_new` is the final output.

```
# Set seed for reporducibility
set.seed(123)

# Create df1
a<-sample(1:10, 10)
b<- sample(1:10,10) 
c<- sample(1:10,10) 
d<-sample(1:10, 10)
df1<- as.data.frame(cbind(a, b, c, d))

# Create df2
index1<- c(1:10)
index2 <- sample(1:1000, 10)
df2<- as.data.frame(cbind(index1, index2))

# Load packages
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df1_new <- df1 %>%
  mutate(ID = 1:n()) %>%
  gather(Column, index1, -ID) %>%
  left_join(df2, by = "index1") %>%
  select(-index1) %>%
  spread(Column, index2) %>%
  select(-ID)
```

Answer (score 0):

This question can be solved by combining two approaches:

1. translating the `index1` values into `index2` values by joining the "mapping" table `df2` with `df1`,
2. reshaping `df1` to avoid to treat each column individually.
   dcast()

For the latter, `melt()` is used to reshape from wide to long format, and `dcast()` to reshape from long to wide format.

```
library(data.table)
# coercing to data.table
DT1 <- data.table(df1)
DT2 <- data.table(df2)
# reshape from wide to long format,
# join with mapping table,
# finally, reshape from long to wide format, remove row count
dcast(DT2[melt(DT1[, rn := .I], id.vars = "rn"), on = .(index1 = value)],
      rn ~ variable, value.var = "index2")[, rn := NULL][]
```

> ```
>       a   b   c   d
>  1: 924 197 852 405
>  2: 241 241 877 852
>  3: 421 772 646 772
>  4: 877 877 924 241
>  5: 852 405 241 421
>  6: 646 852 197 924
>  7: 772 924 772 854
>  8: 854 854 405 877
>  9: 405 646 421 646
> 10: 197 421 854 197
> ```